# Unsatisfied Link Error - OpenCV on Debian BeagleBoneBlack

Tags: java, opencv, arm, debian, beagleboneblack

I have tried to build openCV for Java to run it on a BeagleBoneBlack. My problem is, that when i cross compile it for arm, it still gives me an error message saying that it load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform. I've tried to use following guide for this:
http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/05/24/building-cross-compiling-opencv-for-linux-arm/
And i followed this guide:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

i do include the generated jar into the Java project, and also add openCV as a native library. Additionaly i put the .so into the jre/arm folder for the baglebone black...

Here is the complete error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/arm/libopencv_java300.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/arm/libopencv_java300.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
    at open.main(open.java:9)
    ... 5 more
```

Thanks a lot for the help!